# IE issues with navigation menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have nested ul tags under my standard ul - li tags, and apparently IE is having trouble displaying this properly. Ex:

```
<ul>
 <li>things</li>
 <li>more
  <ul>
   <li>more1</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Everything looks fine in Firefox and Chrome, but I just noticed that it's not working in IE 7, 8 or 9. You can see what I mean here: http://bovinsnbcattle.ca/

I would gladly appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance, 
Bob

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in IE versio 10

Edited After code shown by you

You can not use ul tag in li tag so close li tag

or u can use it as

```
     <ul>
       <li>
         <li>
           <ul>
           <li>
          <li>
         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Hope it wil work for you

Comment: Thanks :) ... but everyone using this site using IE8 and 9. I think I know what's causing the problem (edited above), but I just don't know about how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra ending li tag in there..., funny how I always figure it out after posting, but scratch my head for hours before doing so :/